# Searchkit Checkbox Filter

Tags: searchkit

I am having trouble with Searchkit Checkbox Filter. This is link to documentation with example.
http://docs.searchkit.co/stable/docs/components/navigation/checkbox-filter.html

Is is possible to have two checkbox's inside of a Checkbox Filter?
Or if i need to filters how can I group them together?

For example in the link you can see that we have `Rated` and the checkbox `Rated R` and I would like to have ex. `Rated R` and `Rated +18`

Answer (score -1):

You can only put on checkbox on a Checkbox Filter. But you can group Checkbox Filter inside a div and play around with the css or you can use RefinementListFilter instead.. let me know if that helps.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)